# Debian offline dist-upgrade in one step

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

Is there a way to perform a distribution upgrade on an offline Debian system by making only one return trip to an online machine?

I've managed to perform the equivalent of `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` on an offline machine using `apt-offline`, but I've had to do it using two return trips to the online machine.

Here is the workflow:

```
# OFFLINE machine:
apt-offline set step1.sig --update --upgrade --upgrade-type dist-upgrade

# The step1.sig file only contains references to Package and Release
# files, not any package names.
# ONLINE machine:
apt-offline get step1.sig --bundle step1.zip

# OFFLINE machine (this is the equivalent of apt-get update):
apt-offline install step1.zip
apt-offline set step2.sig --update --upgrade --upgrade-type dist-upgrade

# The step2.sig file now contains references to deb files.
# ONLINE machine:
apt-offline get step2.sig --bundle step2.zip

# OFFLINE machine (this is the equivalent of apt-get dist-upgrade):
apt-offline install step2.zip
```

I'd be interested in a way to do this with a single return trip between the offline and online machines, using command-line tools (`apt-offline` or other).

I've tried this in the first step, hoping it could make something out of the list of existing packages, but it simply doesn't find anything to upgrade on the first pass, considering what the offline machine currently has in its known packages list (which makes sense):

```
apt-offline set packages.sig --install-packages `aptitude search '~i!~M' -F '%p'`
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the package index file (available packages) and then update the packages set (packages to install) **based on** the updated index file.

- During the first part of the trip from the offline machine to the online machine you can send the desynchronize package index file and the desynchronized package set.
- On the online machine, you can update the package index file **then** update the package set based on the new index file and download the corresponding bundle.
- During the second part of the trip from the online machine to the offline machine, you can send the resulting bundle.

The problem is that

```
apt-offline set upgrade.sig --upgrade
```

use the package index file of the local machine and there is no option to use a different package index file. So you can't run this command on the online machine and have to do a round trip to the offline machine.

The solution will be to tell apt-offline to use a different package index file than the local one but at this time it's not possible. You can patch it or write your own tool.